# Snackbar Vuetify - override method after timeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to ask You how I can define a method which execute after the `timeout`? After that `timeout` i want to execute `$emit` event, but I don't know how  can i do this...

```
<v-snackbar
  v-model="snackbar"
  :color="primary"
  :timeout="5000"
>
  {{ text }}
  <v-btn
    dark
    flat
    @click="snackbar = false"
  >
    Close
  </v-btn>
</v-snackbar>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/snackbars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation there's no event attached to that property, but i will give a solution that responds to your use case, add `timeout` property to your data object as follows :

```
   data() {
         return {
          snackbar:false,
          timeout:6000,
          ....
         }
    }
```

add an event handler to your button click :

```
     <v-btn block
       color="primary" 
       dark
       @click="showSnackbar">
       Show Snackbar
    </v-btn>
```

in your methods add `showSnackbar` method

```
    methods: {
         showSnackbar() {
           this.snackbar=true;
           setTimeout(() => { this.$emit("yourEvent"); },this.timeout);
         }
       }
```

I simulate a your case in this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/jOrdaNg)

Comment: you're welcome, sorry i didn't understand your use case

Comment: One snackbar appears for let's say 2000 milsec and disappre and another one appears

Comment: please check this https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/JjKxZyG

Comment: what do you mean by loop?

Comment: please post a detailed question and give me question link

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a watcher. Watch for `snackbar === false`, then execute the function.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to execute something after the timeout is to use the native [events](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-snackbar/#events) provided from the v-snackbar component. In Vuetify 2 it is `@input` whether in Vuetify3 is `@update:modelValue`. Here is an example:

```js
<template>
    <v-snackbar v-model="message.status" :color="message.type" :bottom="true" :right="true" :timeout="timeout" @input="hide()">
        {{ message.text }}

        <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
            <v-btn class="mr-0" v-bind="attrs" text icon @click="hide">
                <v-icon color="white">mdi-close</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: 'Message',
        data() {
            return {
                timeout: 6000
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['message'])
        },
        methods: {
            hide() {
                this.$store.commit('hideMessage')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So, here the `hide()` method will be executed when click `close` button or when it is timed out.